# Days passed between two java date with different timezone

Tags: java, excel, date, time, timezone

I got two Date but one is CET and the other is CEST.

```
   Calendar calFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
            calFrom.set( 2013, 2, 20,0,0,0);
            Calendar calTo = Calendar.getInstance();
            calTo.set( 2013, 3, 5,0,0,0);

        long daysPassed= (calTo.getTime().getTime() - calFrom.getTime().getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        System.out.println("calFrom: " + calFrom.getTime());
        System.out.println("calTo: " + calTo.getTime());
        System.out.println("daysPassed: " + daysPassed);
```

The output says:

```
calFrom: Wed Mar 20 00:00:00 CET 2013
calTo: Fri Apr 05 00:00:00 CEST 2013
daysPassed: 15
```

However Microsoft excel says the difference between the two days is **16**!

How it is possible to calculate the days passed like Excel?

Comment: Are you saying that Java calculation ignores time zone offset?
Calendar.getTime() Javadoc says: "Returns a Date object representing this Calendar's time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch")."
That might be the reason why, i.e. it gets the time from Epoch, without considering time zone.
In Java 8, there is a new Date-Time API, superseding the existing Calendar & Date API in previous JDKs.
See here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html especially the 'Duration' section. I never try it myself. If this can solve your problem, please share it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know Java 8 have a new date API but in my company we are not able yet to use java 8. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JodaTime seems like to handle this issue: 
http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda/